# Is there any neural network whose output can be probabilistic, just like multi-class logistic regression?

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, neural-networks

I want to add nonlinear character into multi-class logistic regression. I know kernel logistic regression can do it. Is there any kind of neural network which has similar characteristic?

Comment: If you want an output between zero and one can't you just use a logit/sigmoid activation function on your output layer nodes? I don't see how the output would differ conceptually from logistic regression.

Comment: But multi-class probabilistic result can not be gained by using just one output between zero and one. I know Pairwise Coupling can solve it. Is there any NN model that can do it more directly?

Comment: So you should have one output node for each class. Each output will be a probability of membership of that class. However they won't all add up to 1.

Comment: And then use Maximum likelihood to train the NN model?

Comment: Just normal back propagation I would think...

Comment: I know Probabilistic Neural Network has summation layer with several nodes for all the classes. But its output layer is one certain class. So that it can be trained using BP. I am a little bit confused and I need to think about your answer for a while. Thanks so much:)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, most good implementations of [multi-layer perceptron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilayer_perceptron) (e.g. [netlab](http://www.aston.ac.uk/eas/research/groups/ncrg/resources/netlab/)) and [Radial Basis Function neural networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function_network) ought to support this, using a [softmax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function) output function and cross-entropy loss function.  See section 6.9 of Chris Bishop's excellent book "[Neural Networks for Pattern Recognition](http://ukcatalogue.oup.com/product/9780198538646.do)"